# How to copy data that is adjacent of a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some code that copy and pastes data onto another sheet using two strings as the range. These strings are in "B" and I need the data between them in columns "C" and "D" to be pasted into B2 and C2 on "PriorityProgress" I am not intrested in the data in column "B" Other then the String I use for the Start of the range.

The code I've written works on a button click and finds the two strings that set the range in column "B" and pastes all the data between the strings in "B" fine but not sure how to go about getting the data in columns "C" and "D" to paste into columns "B" and "C".

```
Dim r As Range, fr As String    'First Range implementation stage
Dim c As Range, fc As String    'End Range ER's at 25
Dim StartR As Integer
Dim EndR As Integer

fr = "Originating Project ERs at Implementation Stage"
fc = "Originating Project ERs at 25"
Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=fr, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set c = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=fc, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    StartR = r.Row + 1
Else
    MsgBox fr & " not found"
End If
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    EndR = c.Row - 1
Else
    MsgBox fc & " not found"
End If
If r.Row And c.Row > 1 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(r, c).Copy
    Worksheets("PriorityProgress").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
End If
```

Here Is some sample data of what I am hoping to acheive:

[Updated Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5csrZ.png)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data? Or a sample data?

Comment: I've attacted a screenshot of some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this is easy. You need to edit your code at the end.

```
If r.Row And c.Row > 1 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(r, c).Copy
    Worksheets("PriorityProgress").Range("C2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Worksheets("PriorityProgress").Range("D2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
End If
```

Please note that this code pastes formula's in Column C & D. If you need to paste the values with the formula's, you need to use below code instead.

```
If r.Row And c.Row > 1 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(r, c).Copy
    Worksheets("PriorityProgress").Range("C2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("PriorityProgress").Range("D2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End If
```

Comment: This Seems to copy the data from "B" to "C" and "D" where as I need the data from columns "C" and "D" put into columns "B" and "C" sorry I did not make this clear.

Comment: Do you mean replace the data existing the B & C with the data from C & D?

Comment: No, let me try explain better. The screenshot is of data in "Sheet1" I need the data on Sheet1 in columns "C" and "D" Pasted onto "priorityProgress" In columns "B" and "C"  So effectivly shifting the data Left by one column.

Comment: Your comments in the question and here are not consistent. In the question you mentioned "getting the data in columns "C" and "D" to paste into columns "C" and "D". And here it looks different.

I would recommend adding a screenshot with sample data(not like "needed data")  but maybe A,B,C,D and then provide a screenshot with your desired output for A,B,C,D

Comment: It seems I made a typo on the original question. I have attachted a new set of sample data that shoudl show what I am hoping to acheive more clearly.